# Replace content of each files with it's header values in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a directory with several text files and I access that all files in spark as follows,

```
JavaRDD<String> filesRDD = sc.textFile(directoryName);
```

In each file, the first line is a header which contains some mapping values. eg:-

```
"1,apple|4,banana|3,lemon"
```

that means if, in the content, there is a "3", it maps to "lemon".

Example of the content as follows,

```
I like 1
John eat 3 and 1
```

and so on.

Now What I need to do is, I need to filter lines from the content first and assign original values from the mapping. For example, the first filter by the string `"like"` and I get `"I like 1"` then, I replace with mapping, then `"I like  apple"`

Please note that this mapping header is different from each file. How can I do this? Since I'm new to spark, I don't have much idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
var fruitPair = sc.parallelize(List("1,apple","4,banana","3,lemon")).map{ str => 
    var temp = str.split(",")
    (temp(0), temp(1))
}
fruitPair.toDF.show()
```

```
+---+------+
| _1|    _2|
+---+------+
|  1| apple|
|  4|banana|
|  3| lemon|
+---+------+
```

```
var contents = List("I like 1", "John eat 3 and 1")

var results = contents.map { content => 
    var tmpContent = content
    fruitPair.collect.foreach { item => 
        var index = tmpContent.indexOf(item._1)
        if (index >= 0) {
            tmpContent = tmpContent.replace(item._1, item._2)
        }
    }
    tmpContent
}

results.foreach{ it => println(it) }
```

```
I like apple
John eat lemon and apple
results: List[String] = List(I like apple, John eat lemon and apple)
```